# $4\mid(p-1) \implies$ there is an element $x$ of order $ 4$ modulo $p$.?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

"$p \equiv 1 \mod 4 \implies 4 \mid (p-1) \implies$ there is an element $x$ of order $4$ modulo $p$."

I am having a difficult time understanding why this implies there is an element $x$ of order $4$. 
Wouldn't this be assuming the converse of Lagrange's Theorem is true when it is only true for prime divisors? I'm speaking of Lagrange's Theorem from group theory.

Comment: This is a very valid question!

Comment: From this(http://math453fall2008.wikidot.com/lecture-23)  for $d∣p−1,$ the polynomial $x^d−1\equiv0\pmod p$ has exactly $d$ roots $\pmod p$.

Comment: Oh! And 4 divides p-1. Thus $x^4-1$ has exactly 4 roots implying there is an element of order 4. Got it, thanks! 
If you type it in as an answer I'll give you the points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The group of units modulo $p$ is *cyclic*: therefore, for every divisor of the group order, there is an element with that order.

Comment: The group order is p, the the only divisors of p are 1 and p. 
4 is not a divisor of p.

Comment: @Adam: We're talking about the multiplicative group of units, not the additive group of all elements.

Comment: Oh I see, and the order of the multiplicative group of units is p-1. Okay I see, thanks.